# Attributes of action layout element

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, layout

Look at the below layout which is from "*base/default/layout/contacts.xml*".

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled">
            <label>Contact Us</label>
            <url>contacts</url>
            <title>Contact Us</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

What I understand from above layout is: (*please let me know if I am wrong about something*)

- The blocks will be added in to the "*default*" layout handle.
- The block "footer_links" is being referred which is in "*page.xml*"

  ```
  <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
  ```
- The "footer_links" has *type*:  "page/template_links" which is calling the class "Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links".
- The "*action*" layout element is calling a method **addLink** from "Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links" class.
- The "*translate*" attribute is used for language specific changes.

What I want to understand is:

- What does "*module*" and "*ifconfig*" attributes are used for in "*action*" layout element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`module` defines the module which is used for the translation like `Mage::helper(<module>)->__(<label>|<title>)`.

Magento has different files and modules for translation, there is a lot of documentation in the net and here on magento.se.

And `ifconfig` checks for a config setting, if this is true, the method is called.

So `addLink` is only called if `Mage::getStoreConfig('contacts/contacts/enabled')` evaluates to true. This configuration setting is set in the backend, I think under System > Configuration > ??? > Contact us(?). Have a look for it :-)

And to extend your statement:

- The `action` layout element is calling a method `addLink` from "Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links" class.

Correct - if `page/template_links` wasn't rewritten.

Comment: I am not from PHP background. This is going from top of my head. I understood  only the part which is after this line "_And to extend your statement:_". Where is this "contacts/contacts/enabled" ?

Comment: please atleast provide me a link :)

Comment: When you are not from PHP background, you are directly driving to hell. Magento is very complex. First learn PHP, then learn magento. Trust me :)

Comment: No time for it :(.. Anyway thanks for your edit. I did understand the function of `ifconfig` :) but still I need to understand `module`.. (_I can understand basics of PHP because I am from javascript background_)